# How to prove $\oint \frac{\pi\csc(πz)}{(2z+1) \cosh\left(\frac{\pi}{2} (2z+1)\right) } \,\mathrm dz ≈ 0$

Tags: calculus, integration

In proving the  $\displaystyle\frac{200}{\pi} \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)  \cosh\left((2k+1)  \frac\pi2\right) }= 25$ I use the below integral, because in calculation the integral by the residue theorem, the series appear and I can evaluate the amount of the series:

$$\oint\frac{\pi \csc(\pi z)}{(2z+1)  \cosh\left(\frac\pi2 (2z+1)\right) }  \,\mathrm dz $$

I mean by solving the below equation I can find the amount of the series:

$$\oint\frac{\pi \csc(\pi z)}{(2z+1)  \cosh\left(\frac\pi2 (2z+1)\right) } \,\mathrm  dz =2\pi i \left(- \frac \pi2+ 4\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)  \cosh\left((2n+1)  \frac\pi2\right)}\right) $$

I cannot understand why the left tends to $0$, As $n\to\infty$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please take a look at the [Mathjax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?lq=1).

Comment: [Proving $\frac{200}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)\cosh\left(\frac{\pi}{2}(2n+1)\right)}=25$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1051688/proving-frac200-pi-sum-n-0-infty-frac-1n2n1-cosh-left-fra)

Comment: @ integrator thanks for your editting. In The Link, Just mention that it tends to 0, but there is no proof!

Comment: **Hint :** Use $ML$ property $$\left|\int_C f(z)\; dz\right|\le ML$$

Comment: @ Venus please explain more or link me to a website. I didnot get what youmean.