# Prove a sum involving hyperbolic functions using residues

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus, contour-integration

In [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1051688/), I succeed in proving one-dimensional cases.
Here is a high dimensional example:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 
\frac{(-1)^{n+k}}{n^2k^2\sqrt{n^2+k^2}\sinh\left ( \pi\sqrt{n^2+k^2}  \right ) }
 +\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^5\sinh(\pi n)} 
=-\frac{\pi^5}{11340}.$$
The above sum comes from $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} 
\frac{(-1)^{n+k+j}}{n^2k^2}\frac{1}{n^2+k^2+j^2}.$$
I am sure that it can establish a relationship with high dimensional residues. But I still don't know how to do that. I will be thankful for all the help.

> **Theorem (Residue theorem).** 
> If a function $f$ is meromorphic in $D\subset\mathbb{C}^n$, and $P$ is a polar-set of $f$, then for any $n$-dimensional cycle $\sigma\subset D\backslash P$,
> $$
> \int_\sigma f(z)\mathrm{d}z
> =(2\pi i)^n\sum_{\mu=1}^{\rho}k_\mu R_\mu.
> $$

Comment: Using symmetry we have $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} 
\frac{(-1)^{n+k+j}}{n^2k^2}\frac{1}{n^2+k^2+j^2} = \frac{1}{3}(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2})^3 $$
Now, instead using the symmetry, try to do the triple sum with respect to $k$.

Comment: @pisco You might misunderstnd what I asked. I am actually interested in evaluating the sum through some unconventional ways. As I mentioned, one of the possible ways is computing high dimensional residues.