# Hyper-closed-forms of series involving hyperbolic functions:$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^2\cosh(\pi n)^2},\frac{\tanh(\pi n)}{n^3}$ and the like.

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, hypergeometric-function, hyperbolic-functions

Series like
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2\cosh(\pi n)^2},\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\tanh\left ( \pi n \right ) }{n^3}
$$
that used to be recognised as ones with no closed-forms, however, actually could be expressed by (generalized) hypergeometric series(being **hyper-closed**). We have
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2\cosh(\pi n)^2} 
=S+\frac{3\pi^2}{4}-6\pi\ln(2),\\
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\tanh(\pi n)}{n^3} 
=\pi S+\frac{5\pi^3}{12}-6\pi^2\ln(2)+4\pi G,\\
&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}
\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2\sinh\left ( \frac\pi2(2n+1) \right )^2} 
=\frac14S +\frac{\pi^2}{48}-\frac{3\pi}2\ln(2)+2G,\\
&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\coth\left ( \frac\pi2(2n+1) \right ) }{
(2n+1)^3} 
=-\frac{\pi}{8}S
-\frac{\pi^3}{96}+\frac{3\pi^2}4\ln(2)-\frac{\pi G}2,
\end{aligned}
where $S=\frac{7}{2}{}_6F_5\left ( \frac34,\frac34,1,1,1,\frac{15}8;
\frac78,\frac54,\frac54,2,2;1 \right ) 
+\frac{\pi}{8}{}_5F_4\left ( 1,1,\frac32,\frac32,\frac32;2,2,2,2;1 \right )$ and $G=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}$ denotes Catalan's constant. Mathematica codes for numerical verification:
`NSum[1/(n^2Cosh[Pi n]^2),{n,1,Infinity}] N[7/2HypergeometricPFQ[{3/4,3/4,1,1,1,15/8},{7/8,5/4,5/4,2,2},1]+Pi/8HypergeometricPFQ[{1,1,3/2,3/2,3/2},{2,2,2,2},1]+3Pi^2/4-6Pi Log[2]]`
`NSum[Tanh[Pi n]/(n^3),{n,1,Infinity}] N[7Pi/2HypergeometricPFQ[{3/4,3/4,1,1,1,15/8},{7/8,5/4,5/4,2,2},1]+Pi^2/8HypergeometricPFQ[{1,1,3/2,3/2,3/2},{2,2,2,2},1]+5Pi^3/12-6Pi^2Log[2]+4Pi Catalan]`.

---

*Question.* Are these results known in literature? Could you provide any other ideas to prove the equalities? The original process is somewhat cumbersome, and I'll capture it in my answer(under this question) very soon.

Comment: It's a bit of a stretch to call a hypergeometric series a closed form.

Comment: @GerryMyerson. With time going, I wonder more and more about the limits or bounds of the concept of closed form.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici You may want to look at *Closed Forms: What They Are and Why We Care* by **JM Borwein**.

Comment: This is very interesting for sure.

Comment: This might be interesting, [On the curious series related to the elliptic integrals](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.01937.pdf)

Answer (score 8):

Our goal is to show
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}
\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2\sinh\left ( \frac\pi2(2n+1) \right )^2} 
=\frac14S +\frac{\pi^2}{48}-\frac{3\pi}2\ln(2)+2G.$$
*The First Step.*(as a hint) We consider
$
\sum_{m\ge0,n\ge1}n^3e^{-\pi xn(2m+1)}
=\frac{1}{16}\vartheta_2(q)^4\vartheta_3(q)^4.
$
Therefore it's easy to show
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}
\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2\sinh\left ( \frac\pi2(2n+1) \right )^2}
=\frac{\pi^2}{4} \int_{1}^{\infty}(x-1)\vartheta_2(q)^4\vartheta_3(q)^4
\text{d}x,
$$
which is solved to be the aforementioned hypergeometric series.

---

On the one hand, by integrating $f_1(z)=\frac{\pi \tan(\pi z)}{z^2\sinh(\pi z)^2},f_2(z)=\frac{\pi \cot(\pi z)\tanh(\pi z)}{z^3}$ and residue theorem, gives
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left ( \frac2\pi
\frac{\tanh(\pi n)}{n^3}-\frac{1}{n^2\cosh(\pi n)}  \right ) 
=S+\frac{\pi^2}{12}-6\pi\ln(2)+8G,\\
&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\coth\left ( \frac\pi2(2n+1) \right ) }{(2n+1)^3} 
=\frac{\pi^3}{24} -\frac18\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
\frac{\tanh(\pi n)}{n^3}.
\end{aligned}
On the other hand, compute
$
\sum_{(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^2}\frac{1}{\left [ 
\left ( m+\frac12 \right ) ^2+n^2\right ]^2 } =4\pi^2G
$,
from which we could find
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left ( \frac2\pi
\frac{\tanh(\pi n)}{n^3}-\frac{2}{n^2\cosh(\pi n)}  \right ) 
=8G-\frac{2\pi^2}3.\square
$$

---

Here are some relative results.
**Entry 1.**
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\coth(\pi n)}{n^3} 
=\frac{7\pi^3}{180},\\
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^3\left ( e^{2\pi n}-1 \right )
  } =\frac{7\pi^3}{360}-\frac{1}{2}\zeta(3),\\
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2\sinh(\pi n)^2} 
=\frac23G-\frac{11\pi^2}{180},\\
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\coth(\pi n)}{n\sinh(\pi n)^2}=\frac\pi{30}-\frac{G}{3\pi}.
\end{aligned}
**Entry 2.**
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\tanh(\pi n)}{n^3} 
=\pi S+\frac{5\pi^3}{12}-6\pi^2\ln(2)+4\pi G,\\
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^3\left ( e^{2\pi n}+1 \right )
  } =\frac{1}{2}\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi}{2} S
-\frac{5\pi^3}{24}+3\pi^2\ln(2)-2\pi G,\\
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2\cosh(\pi n)^2} 
=S+\frac{3\pi^2}{4}-6\pi\ln(2),\\
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\tanh(\pi n)}{n\cosh(\pi n)^2}=-\frac\pi2+\frac32\ln(2)+\frac{2G}\pi-\frac1{32}\,_5F_4\left ( 1,1,\frac32,\frac32,\frac32;2,2,2,2;1 \right ),
\end{aligned}
where $S=\frac{7}{2}{}_6F_5\left ( \frac34,\frac34,1,1,1,\frac{15}8;
\frac78,\frac54,\frac54,2,2;1 \right ) 
+\frac{\pi}{8}{}_5F_4\left ( 1,1,\frac32,\frac32,\frac32;2,2,2,2;1 \right )$.
**Entry 3.**
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\tanh\left ( \frac\pi2(2n+1) \right ) }{(2n+1)^3} 
=\frac{\pi^3}{32} ,\\
&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^3\left ( e^{\pi(2n+1)}+1 \right ) } 
=\frac7{16}\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^3}{64} ,\\
&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1 }
{(2n+1)^2\cosh\left ( \frac\pi2(2n+1) \right )^2 }
=\frac{\pi^2}{16}-\frac{G}{2},\\
&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\tanh\left ( \frac\pi2(2n+1) \right ) }
{(2n+1)\cosh\left ( \frac\pi2(2n+1) \right )^2 }
=\frac{G}{2\pi}.
\end{aligned}
**Entry 4.**
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\coth\left ( \frac\pi2(2n+1) \right ) }{(2n+1)^3} 
=-\frac{\pi}{8}S
-\frac{\pi^3}{96}+\frac{3\pi^2}4\ln(2)-\frac{\pi G}2,\\
&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^3\left ( e^{\pi(2n+1)}-1 \right ) } 
=-\frac7{16}\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi}{16}S
-\frac{\pi^3}{192}+\frac{3\pi^2}8\ln(2)-\frac{\pi G}4,\\
&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1 }
{(2n+1)^2\sinh\left ( \frac\pi2(2n+1) \right )^2 }
=\frac14S +\frac{\pi^2}{48}-\frac{3\pi}2\ln(2)+2G,\\
&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\coth\left ( \frac\pi2(2n+1) \right ) }
{(2n+1)\sinh\left ( \frac\pi2(2n+1) \right )^2 }
=\frac34\ln(2)-\frac{G}\pi-\frac1{64}\,_5F_4\left ( 1,1,\frac32,\frac32,\frac32;2,2,2,2;1 \right ).
\end{aligned}
**Entry 5.**
$$
\displaystyle
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3\cosh\left ( \frac\pi2
(2n+1) \right ) } 
=\frac{\pi^3}{32}+\frac{\pi^2}{8}-\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^4 }{16\pi}
+\frac{\pi^2}{8}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}
\frac{\left ( \frac12 \right )_n^3 }{(1)_n^3} \frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^4}{64}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left ( \frac12 \right )_n^2}{(1)_n^2}
\frac{1}{(4n+3)^2},
$$
$$
\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)\sinh\left ( \frac\pi2(2n+1) \right )^2 }
=\frac{1}{8}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\Gamma\left ( \frac{n}2 \right )
\Gamma\left ( \frac{n+1}{2}  \right )  }{\Gamma\left ( \frac{n}2+\frac34 \right )^2 }.
$$
**Entry 6.**
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n+1} 
\frac{\sinh\left ( \pi\left ( n+\frac12 \right )  \frac{K^\prime}{K} \right ) }{
\cosh\left ( 2\pi\left ( n+\frac12 \right )  \frac{K^\prime}{K} \right )} 
=\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{artanh} \left ( 
\sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt{1-k^2} }{2} }  \right ),\\
&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} 
\frac{\cosh\left ( \pi\left ( n+\frac12 \right )  \frac{K^\prime}{K} \right ) }{
\cosh\left ( 2\pi\left ( n+\frac12 \right )  \frac{K^\prime}{K} \right )} 
=\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{arctan} \left ( 
\sqrt{\frac{1/\sqrt{1-k^2}-1 }{2} }  \right ),\\
&\sum_{m_i\in\mathbb{Z}}
\frac{1}{\cosh\left ( \pi\sqrt{m_1^2+m_2^2+m_3^2}  \right ) }
=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^4 }{2\sqrt{2}\pi^3 },\\
&\sum_{m,n\ge0} \frac{(-1)^m}{\sqrt{(2m+1)(2n+1)} 
\sinh\left ( \frac\pi2\sqrt{(2m+1)(2n+1)}  \right ) }
=\frac12,\\
&{}_9F_8\left ( \left \{ \frac12 \right \}_8,\frac54 ;\frac14,\left \{  1\right \} _7;1 \right )
=\frac{1024}{3\pi}  \sum_{m_i\ge0}\frac{(-1)^{m_1+m_2+m_3}\left ( m_1+\frac12 \right )(m_2+\frac12)(m_3+\frac12) }{
\cosh\left ( \pi\sqrt{\left ( m_1+\frac12 \right )^2 
+\left ( m_2+\frac12 \right )^2+\left ( m_3+\frac12 \right )^2 }  \right ) }.
\end{aligned}
**Entry 7.**
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^3\sinh(\pi n)} = -\frac{\pi}{8}S-\frac{2\pi^3}{45}+\frac{3\pi^2}{4}\ln(2) 
-\frac{\pi G}{2},\\
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\coth(\pi n)}{n^2\sinh(\pi n)} 
=\frac{1}{8}S+\frac{23\pi^2}{360}-\frac{3\pi}{4}\ln(2) 
+\frac{5 G}{12},\\
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^3\sinh(\pi n)} =-\frac{\pi^3}{360},\\
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n\coth(\pi n)}{n^2\sinh(\pi n)} 
=\frac{\pi^2}{45}-\frac{G}{3},\\
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n\sinh(\pi n)^3} 
=-\frac{17\pi}{240}+\frac{G}{6\pi}+\frac{1}{4}\ln(2).
\end{aligned}
**Entry 8.** 3 remarkable integrals:
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{K^\prime{}^2}{\sqrt{k}K }\text{d}k
=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{K\left ( \sqrt{1-k^2}  \right ) ^2}{\sqrt{k}K(k) }\text{d}k
=3\pi^2\ln(2)-\frac{\pi^2}{16} \,_5F_4\left ( 1,1,\frac32,\frac32,\frac32;2,2,2,2;1 \right ),
$$
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{K^\prime{}^2}{K}\frac1{\sqrt{1-k^2} }\text{d}k
=\frac{3\pi^2}4\ln(2)-\frac{\pi^2}{64} \,_5F_4\left ( 1,1,\frac32,\frac32,\frac32;2,2,2,2;1 \right ),
$$
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{K^\prime}{K}\frac{\text{d}k}{\sqrt{k}(1-k^2)^{3/4}}
=\frac{5\pi}{2}\ln(2)-\frac{\pi}{16}
\,_4F_3\left ( 1,1,\frac32,\frac32;2,2,2;\frac12 \right ),$$
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{K^\prime}{K} 
\frac{\text{d}k}{(1-k^2)^{3/4}} 
=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2} }\,_3F_2\left ( \frac12,\frac12,\frac12;1,\frac32;\frac12 \right ),
$$

$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{K^\prime}{K} 
\frac{\text{d}k}{\sqrt{k}\sqrt{1-k^2}} 
=\sqrt{2}\pi\,_3F_2\left ( \frac12,\frac12,\frac12;1,\frac32;\frac12 \right ),
$$and a hypergeometric identity:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left ( \frac12 \right )_n^5 }{(1)_n^5}
(4n+1) 
=\frac{2\sqrt{2}\,\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^2 }{\pi^{5/2}}
\,_4F_3\left ( \frac14,\frac14,\frac14,\frac14;\frac12,\frac12,1;1 \right )
-\frac{2}{\pi}\,_4F_3\left ( \frac14,\frac12,\frac12,\frac12;\frac34,1,1;1 \right )
$$
with a generalization, for any $\Re(s)>0$,
$$
\,_7F_6\left ( \left \{ \frac12 \right \}_5,\frac{5}{4},1-s;
s+\frac12,\frac14,\left \{ 1 \right \}_4;1   \right ) 
=4^{1-s}
\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^2\Gamma(2s) }{\pi^2\,\Gamma\left ( s+\frac14 \right )^2 }
\,_4F_3 \left ( \frac14,\frac14,s,s;s+\frac14,s+\frac14,1;1 \right ) 
-\frac{2}{\pi}\,_4F_3\left ( \left \{ \frac12 \right \}_3,s;s+\frac12,1,1;1   \right ).
$$
**Entry 9.** An integral derived by a hyperbolic series(with a nasty looking):
$$
\int_{0}^{\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}  }{4} } 
\frac{(1-2k^2)(1-136k^2+136k^4)}{\sqrt{1-k^2} }
\left ( K^\prime-\sqrt{3}K  \right ) ^6\text{d}k
=\frac{\pi^7}{16}.
$$

**Entry 10.** We involve some hypergeometric cases.
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\tanh\left ( \pi\left ( n+\frac12 \right )
\frac{K^\prime}{K}   \right ) }{(2n+1)\cosh\left ( \pi\left ( n+\frac12 \right )  
\frac{K^\prime}{K}\right ) } 
=\frac{k}2\,_3F_2\left ( \frac12,\frac12,\frac12;1,\frac32;k^2 \right )
,$$

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n\tanh(\pi n)}{n\cosh(\pi n)}
=\sqrt{2}\,_3F_2\left ( \frac12,\frac12,\frac12;1,\frac32;1 \right )  -\frac\pi2.
$$

Comment: for previous efforts(though they are trivial):https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1051688/